# Possible to show the same object (textbox that display a menu when) with the same name and referencing the same macros/vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, events, handler

I have emulated a hamburger menu (implemented as a textbox) that triggers a dropdown with various options that I want to display various tabs of an Excel workbook (though the specific purpose of the textbox is not relevant to my question). Is it possible to show the same textbox object (or any other object) with the same name and calling the same macros/vba code? I would like to avoid having to write a separate [tbName]_click, etc. event handlers for the each tab where I want it to appear (and will eventually want to have the hamburger menu displayed on various pages dynamically -- but that's a subject for another day).

Thx...

D.

Comment: You can improve the quality of your question by posting the code you are using. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

The code for the hamburger menu (for which I already have working code) is implemented as a textbox ,but could be ANY object that triggers a macro when clicked. I don't think posting that code would be helpful. I have not yet begun witing code to place the copies of the object on different tabs. Before I begin writing that code, I was simply hoping for guidance on an APPROACH.-- not so much the code to do so as much as either a verbal description or even simple pseudocode showing how to copy the object from a source tab to a new or different target tab. That, and whether the object, after being copied to the target tab, can have the same name and trigger the same macro. There are other behaviors I want the object to display, but I can figure those out myself, and there's no need to bring them up here.